# How to push labels from Personal to Shared server in Perforce?

Tags: label, perforce, pull-request

How do I fetch and pull labels and jobs between Personal (clone) server and Shared (remote) server in Perforce using P4V visual client?

Answer (score 2):

According to the current documentation the `p4 push` command only pushes files, not metadata entities like labels and jobs:  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_push.html

If you want to transfer labels and jobs between servers you'll need to script some sort of replicator (you may be able to repurpose something like P4DTG for at least some of that work).

Comment: I believe that your "replicator" in many cases can be more-or-less as simple as "p4 -p personal job -o NNN | p4 -p shared job -i". Labels are tougher, though. By the way, 'p4 push' does push fixes, I believe; it just doesn't push jobs.